# Batch file to insert string in exact position in file txt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a `test.txt` file like this:

```
sylvester, stallone, 35,20, florida;
brad, pitt, 40,25, california;
sean, connery, 15,80, london;
```

I have to create a new one in which  the surname begins with the `15`th column and the name in the `30`th.

I would like to do it with a batch file.

What I have managed to do is this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (test.txt) DO (
SET "line=%%H"
SET "spaces=         "        
ECHO (!spaces!!line!!spaces!%%G
)
) >> output.txt
pause
```

But in this way `%%G` does not begin always from the same position, it depends on how many characters has `%%H`. And more, does not write on `output.txt` but it makes me see the results on the batch window.
I know it's probably a trivial question, but I'm new to programming.

Comment: Leave out the space between `ECHO` and `(`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del output.txt
set "spaces=              " :: 15 spaces
(FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%G IN (test.txt) DO (
  SET "line=%spaces%%%H %spaces%"
  set "line=!line:~0,29!"
  echo !line:~0,29!%%G
)) >output.txt
```

add 14 spaces in front of the surname (to let surename start at 15) and append another 15 spaces (to get a cumulated length of at least 29). Then trim it to the first 29 characters and append the name (at Pos 30).
(added a space to the delims for proper handling)